# How to update a database table in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I'm trying to update table data from a database in CakePHP.

Query:

```
UPDATE status SET amount=5000 WHERE id=3
```

How to write this query in CakePHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at documentation and see the [CakePHP way of dealing with models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) (and database tables).

In this case I think you could use `set()` and `save()`:

```
$this->Status->read(null, 3);
$this->Status->set('amount', 5000);
$this->Status->save();
```

or a shorter version with `saveField()`:

```
$this->Status->id = 3; // This avoids the query performed by read()
$this->Status->saveField('amount', 5000);
```

The difference between them is that `saveField()` is kind of an atomic update, while multiple `set()` calls do not modify the data until you do a `save()` call.

Comment: $this->Status->id = 3; should also be an appropriate way to start an update.

Comment: @Anthony You're right. In fact, I tend to use that instead of `read()`. I have updated the answer to reflect both options